decoder.ptr was nullptr CreateDesktopWindowTarget - IDesktopWindowTarget
In C++, I want to load a image, and render it to a win32 window using winrt compositing. I'm just trying to build a simple test bed for my other app to test 2dtexture compositing.
I've tried many implementations at this point.
void CreateDesktopWindowTarget(HWND window)
{
    namespace abi = ABI::Windows::UI::Composition::Desktop;

    auto interop = m_compositor.as<abi::ICompositorDesktopInterop>();
    DesktopWindowTarget target{ nullptr };
    check_hresult(interop->CreateDesktopWindowTarget(window, false, reinterpret_cast<abi::IDesktopWindowTarget**>(put_abi(target))));
    m_target = target;
}

This is in most of their examples and sample code. It fails here:
    check_hresult(interop->CreateDesktopWindowTarget(window, false, reinterpret_cast<abi::IDesktopWindowTarget**>(put_abi(target))));

with:
C++: Exception thrown: read access violation. decoder.**ptr** was nullptr. (decoder.ptr was nullptr.)

I don't know or understand what any of this abi type reflection stuff is doing. Its hard to debug. The failures are just esoteric.
This scratch file is where I'm at:
#define NOMINMAX
#include <windows.h>
#include <windows.ui.composition.h>
#include <windows.ui.composition.desktop.h>
#include <windows.ui.composition.interop.h>
#include <unknwn.h>       // For IUnknown and related COM interfaces
#include <activation.h>   // For IActivationFactory
#include <roapi.h>        // For RoInitialize, RoUninitialize, RoGetActivationFactory
#include <wrl.h>          // For Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <dxgi1_2.h>
#include <dxgidebug.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <combaseapi.h>

// Link necessary libraries
#pragma comment(lib, "runtimeobject.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dxguid.lib")

#include <wrl/client.h> // For Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr

// WIL (Windows Implementation Library)
#include <wil/cppwinrt.h> // Needs to come before C++/WinRT headers
#include <wil/resource.h>
#include <wil/cppwinrt_helpers.h>
#include <wil/coroutine.h>

// C++/WinRT headers
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.Metadata.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Graphics.Capture.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Graphics.DirectX.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Graphics.DirectX.Direct3D11.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Graphics.Imaging.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Security.Authorization.AppCapabilityAccess.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Storage.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Storage.Pickers.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Storage.Streams.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.System.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Composition.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Composition.Desktop.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Popups.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.Numerics.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Composition.Interactions.h>

// STL headers
#include <atomic>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>
#include <optional>
#include <future>
#include <mutex>

// D3D headers
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3d11_4.h>
#include <dxgi1_6.h>
#include <d2d1_3.h>
#include <wincodec.h>

// Helper headers
#include "ComPtr.hpp"
#include <robmikh.common/composition.interop.h>
#include <robmikh.common/composition.desktop.interop.h>
#include <robmikh.common/d3d11Helpers.h>
#include <robmikh.common/d3d11Helpers.desktop.h>
#include <robmikh.common/direct3d11.interop.h>
#include <robmikh.common/d2dHelpers.h>
#include <robmikh.common/capture.desktop.interop.h>
#include <robmikh.common/dispatcherqueue.desktop.interop.h>
#include <robmikh.common/stream.interop.h>
#include <robmikh.common/hwnd.interop.h>
#include <robmikh.common/ControlsHelper.h>



#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "windowscodecs.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "gdi32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "comctl32.lib")


using namespace winrt;

namespace winrt
{
    using namespace Windows::UI::Composition;
    using namespace Windows::UI::Composition::Desktop;
    using namespace Windows::Graphics::DirectX::Direct3D11;
    using namespace Windows::Foundation;
    using namespace Windows::Foundation::Numerics;

    using namespace Windows::Foundation;
    using namespace Windows::Foundation::Numerics;
    using namespace Windows::Graphics;
    using namespace Windows::Graphics::Capture;
    using namespace Windows::Graphics::DirectX;
    using namespace Windows::Graphics::DirectX::Direct3D11;
    using namespace Windows::System;
    using namespace Windows::UI;
    using namespace Windows::UI::Composition;
    using namespace Windows::System;
    using namespace Windows::UI::Composition::Desktop;
    using namespace Windows::Foundation::Numerics;
}

namespace util
{
    using namespace robmikh::common::uwp;
    using namespace robmikh::common::desktop;
}

winrt::Windows::UI::Composition::Compositor m_compositor{ nullptr };
winrt::Windows::UI::Composition::Desktop::DesktopWindowTarget m_target{ nullptr };
winrt::Windows::UI::Composition::ContainerVisual m_root{ nullptr };
winrt::Windows::UI::Composition::SpriteVisual m_content{ nullptr };
winrt::Windows::UI::Composition::CompositionSurfaceBrush m_brush{ nullptr };
winrt::Windows::Graphics::DirectX::Direct3D11::IDirect3DDevice m_device{ nullptr };
winrt::com_ptr<IDXGISwapChain1> m_swapChain{ nullptr };
winrt::com_ptr<ID3D11Device> m_d3dDevice{ nullptr };
winrt::com_ptr<ID3D11DeviceContext> m_d3dContext{ nullptr };
winrt::Windows::System::DispatcherQueueController m_dispatcherQueueController{ nullptr };


void CreateDesktopWindowTarget(HWND window)
{
    namespace abi = ABI::Windows::UI::Composition::Desktop;

    auto interop = m_compositor.as<abi::ICompositorDesktopInterop>();
    DesktopWindowTarget target{ nullptr };
    check_hresult(interop->CreateDesktopWindowTarget(window, false, reinterpret_cast<abi::IDesktopWindowTarget**>(put_abi(target))));
    m_target = target;
}

void CreateCompositionRoot()
{
    auto root = m_compositor.CreateContainerVisual();
    root.RelativeSizeAdjustment({ 1.0f, 1.0f });
    root.Offset({ 124, 12, 0 });
    m_target.Root(root);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (uMsg == WM_DESTROY)
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

void EnsureDispatcherQueue()
{
    namespace abi = ABI::Windows::System;

    if (m_dispatcherQueueController == nullptr)
    {
        DispatcherQueueOptions options
        {
            sizeof(DispatcherQueueOptions), /* dwSize */
            DQTYPE_THREAD_CURRENT,          /* threadType */
            DQTAT_COM_ASTA                  /* apartmentType */
        };

        winrt::Windows::System::DispatcherQueueController controller{ nullptr };
        check_hresult(CreateDispatcherQueueController(options, reinterpret_cast<abi::IDispatcherQueueController**>(put_abi(controller))));
        m_dispatcherQueueController = controller;
    }
}

int main()
{
    winrt::init_apartment(winrt::apartment_type::multi_threaded);
    EnsureDispatcherQueue();
    auto m_compositor = winrt::Compositor();

    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"FrameShowWindowClass";

    WNDCLASS wc = {};
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    RegisterClass(&wc);

    DWORD style = WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX;
    DWORD exStyle = 0;

    RECT rect = { 0, 0, 1024, 1024 };
    AdjustWindowRectEx(&rect, style, FALSE, exStyle);
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        exStyle,
        CLASS_NAME,
        L"Frame Show",
        style,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        rect.right - rect.left,
        rect.bottom - rect.top,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        wc.hInstance,
        NULL
    );

    if (!hwnd)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);

    const wchar_t CHILD_CLASS_NAME[] = L"ChildWindowClass";

    WNDCLASS child_wc = {};
    child_wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc; 
    child_wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    child_wc.lpszClassName = CHILD_CLASS_NAME;
    child_wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    RegisterClass(&child_wc);

    HWND hwndChild = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        CHILD_CLASS_NAME,
        NULL,
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
        0, 0, 1024, 1024,
        hwnd,
        NULL,
        wc.hInstance,
        NULL
    );


    auto d3dDevice = util::CreateD3D11Device();
    auto dxgiDevice = d3dDevice.as<IDXGIDevice>();
    m_device = CreateDirect3DDevice(dxgiDevice.get());

    auto d2dFactory = util::CreateD2DFactory();
    auto d2dDevice = util::CreateD2DDevice(d2dFactory, d3dDevice);
    winrt::com_ptr<ID2D1DeviceContext> d2dContext;

    ComPtr<IWICImagingFactory> wicFactory;
    CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_WICImagingFactory,
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&wicFactory)
    );

    ComPtr<IWICBitmapDecoder> decoder;
    std::wstring imagePath = L"C:\\data\\train - Copy\\outpu21567151.bmp";
    wicFactory->CreateDecoderFromFilename(
        imagePath.c_str(),
        nullptr,
        GENERIC_READ,
        WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad,
        &decoder
    );

    ComPtr<IWICBitmapFrameDecode> frame;
    decoder->GetFrame(0, &frame);

    ComPtr<IWICFormatConverter> converter;
    wicFactory->CreateFormatConverter(&converter);
    converter->Initialize(
        frame.Get(),
        GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppRGBA,
        WICBitmapDitherTypeNone,
        nullptr,
        0.f,
        WICBitmapPaletteTypeCustom
    );

    UINT width, height;
    converter->GetSize(&width, &height);
    UINT stride = width * 4;
    UINT imageSize = stride * height;
    std::unique_ptr<BYTE[]> pixels(new BYTE[imageSize]);
    converter->CopyPixels(NULL, stride, imageSize, pixels.get());

    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC texDesc = {};
    texDesc.Width = 1024;
    texDesc.Height = 1024;
    texDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    texDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    texDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    texDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    texDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    texDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    texDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    texDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> texture;
    d3dDevice->CreateTexture2D(&texDesc, nullptr, &texture);
    d3dDevice->GetImmediateContext(m_d3dContext.put());
    m_d3dContext->UpdateSubresource(texture.Get(), 0, nullptr, pixels.get(), stride, 0);
    
    CreateDesktopWindowTarget(hwndChild);
    CreateCompositionRoot();
    auto compositionGraphicsDevice = util::CreateCompositionGraphicsDevice(m_compositor, d2dDevice.get());
    auto compositionSurface = util::CreateCompositionSurfaceForSwapChain(m_compositor, texture.Get());
    SpriteVisual spriteVisual = m_compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
    CompositionSurfaceBrush surfaceBrush = m_compositor.CreateSurfaceBrush(compositionSurface);
    spriteVisual.Brush(surfaceBrush);
    spriteVisual.RelativeSizeAdjustment({ 1.0f, 1.0f });
    m_target.Root(spriteVisual);

    MSG msg = {};
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

This is just a scratch file. But I should be able to make this work. If you know, do I have to have a dispatch queue? With screen capture I just init a single thread apartment.

In your main() function, you are creating a new Compositor object and assigning it to a local variable named m_compositor, but your CreateDesktopWindowTarget() function is using a global variable of the same name, which is initialized to nullptr and never re-assigned, so your interop variable ends up as nullptr when casting the global m_compositor variable.
Change this statement in main():
auto m_compositor = winrt::Compositor();

To this instead:
m_compositor = winrt::Compositor();

